# How can I set the portable text editor as default text editor of Git portable?

Tags: windows, git, portable-applications

Windows, Git v2.11 portable

On the current computer my USB-flash drive has `E:` name. But on other computer it can to have other letter (for example `F:` or `G:`)...

My portable Git (v2.11) is located on the `<My USB-drive>:\apps\PortableGit-2.11\` folder. My portable text editor (Sublime Text 3) is located on the `<My USB-drive>:\apps\Sublime-Text-3\` folder.

If I write the `core.editor` value with `E` then it works fine on my current computer (when I launch the `git commit` command):

```
git config --system core.editor "'E:/apps/Sublime-Text-3/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
```

But it will not work on other computers where my USB-drive's name uses other letter.

How can I set the portable text editor as default text editor of Git portable without that problem?
Is it possible to point the path relatively of portable Git location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 enviroment variables that you can use: `HOMEDRIVE` and `EXEPATH`.

`HOMEDRIVE` - the drive that you ran from (eg: `C:`)

`EXEPATH` - the full path of where the git ran from (eg: `"C:\\MyApps\\GitPortable"`)

So you can use those 2 in your gitconfig:

`editor = "$HOMEDRIVE/apps/Sublime-Text-3/sublime_text.exe"`

You need to make sure that the `$HOMEDRIVE` appears in the `gitconfig` file (and not manipulated by the shell, so run `git config --system --edit` and add it directly to there (under `[core]` section). Also make sure the variables are **not** inside single quotes `''`

Answer (score 0):

For windows, to open Notepad++ by example, insert line below in file C:\users<user account>.gitconfig :

```
[core]
    editor = \"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe\" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

controls it : `$ git config --global --list`

```
user.name=<firstName LastName>
user.email=<your email>
merge.tool=kdiff3
diff.guitool=kdiff3
core.editor="C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.rebase=false
fetch.prune=false
rebase.autostash=false
```